# Rails 4 validates uniqueness: {scope: :parent_id} for nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I was wondering whether anybody felt kind enough to help me figure out why this isn't working.

I have a Model lets call it Task which belongs to a Project Model. I basically want each Task to have a unique name per project (`Project1` could have a task called `task1` and so could `Project2` but both could only have one called `task1`) . This seems to be what the :scope option is for but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

The task model is a nested resource within project and as such I call the create action via `project_tasks_path(@project)`. It works fine creating tasks and assigning them to projects but the scope of the uniqueness validation is not taking hold. If I create a task `task1` in `Project1` I can't create one with the same name in task 2.

This is my setup:

**Task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :project_id}
```

**tasks_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @project = Project.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
    @task = Task.new(model_params)
    #print task to stdout
    puts "@task"
    ap @task

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created task"
        format.js
      else
        # no flash as form handles errors
        format.js { render action: 'new' }
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

for some reason when I output the contents of the newly created task, I get the following

```
#<Task:0x007ff7c7c3b178> {
            :id => nil,
          :name => "test",
    :project_id => nil,
    :created_at => nil,
    :updated_at => nil
}
```

It seems that because project_id hasn't been set at this point it's using 'nil' as the value.

What's the best way to get around this? would it just be a custom validator?

**Edit 1**

```
def model_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:name, :project_id)
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting. Do you want the task to be not saved when `project_id` is not set?

Comment: you dont want to save `project_id` as nil values?

Comment: I don't see where you're assigning the project id to the task...@task.project_id = @project.id

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, this is a nested resource. Also, each task has to have a unique name. each project can have a task with a name used in a different project but only one. As for the assignment, again, this is a nested resource, I call create via project_tasks_path(@project)

Comment: I've edited the question to include some more details of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, having been playing around with this, it seems that the way to make this type of validation is pretty straight forward. All it requires is that the nested resource be built in relation to it's project, this forces the :parent_id to be passed through to the validation as expected.

In the case of this toy example, that means that the create action has to look something like:

```
@project = Project.find_by(id: params[:project_id])
@task = @project.tasks.build(model_params)
```

It should be noted that because of Rails not supporting generation of nested resources from the command line, the way that the scaffold generated controllers handle creation is by `Model.new(model_params)` and then saving, this doesn't seem to pick up the `:parent_id` in time for the validation and so will need changing as above (in terms of the parent).